# Get tracking info from order/shipment object

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipment-tracking

How can I get the shipment tracking information from shipment or order object in magento2. Following ways doesn't work for me.

```
$shipment->getTrackingInfo();

$order->getTrackingInfoByOrder();
```

Answer (score 12):

To get the shipping tracking numbers, use the following code.

```
$tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();

foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {

     $trackNumbers[] = $track->getTrackNumber();

}
```

This will return an array of all shipment tracking numbers.

Answer (score 2):

To get track collection object

```
$order->getTracksCollection()->fetchItem();
$order->getTracksCollection()->fetchItem()->getTitle();
$order->getTracksCollection()->fetchItem()->getTrackNumber();
```