# How to cancel order using tracking number in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status, shipment-tracking, cancel-orders

I need to cancel order using tracking number in magento2?

Comment: I want to do it programatically..

Answer (score 0):

simple code to cancel the order

```
   protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterfac $orderRepository,
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function cancel($id)
    {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($id);
        if ($order->canCancel()) {
            $order->cancel();
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);
        }
    }
```

check the below link to get order tracking info.
[Get tracking info from order/shipment object](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221926/get-tracking-info-from-order-shipment-object)

I am not sure using a tracking id to cancel the order is possible or not but you have a tracking id then you can filter orders by tracking id and get order id by order id. you can cancel the order using above code.

Comment: I am getting the tracking no from the above link..

Comment: I am getting the tracking number in the 
 Cancel.php file located in app\code\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order ..in the public function execute() function

Comment: I need  to call the API using tracking number..Can I call the API in the public function execute() of Cancel.php file of app\code\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order

Comment: How to call getConfigData('filedname') method in order cancel module

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

There's no direct way to get the data using the Magento API. An order can have multiple shipments with different tracking numbers.
I suggest you check https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.7-admin/tag/shipments
If you use the search criteria ([see this question as an example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151385/magento-2-searchcriteria-using-rest-apis)), you can specify the tracking number to filter the results.
From there you can get the order_id, which you can then use to cancel the order (see below; answer from @Devidas should also work).

**Original (updated) answer - leaving it here in case it is still useful.**

Tracking numbers are saved in the `sales_shipment_track` table.
See `\Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface::getList` with which you can use search criteria to filter tracks with a specific tracking number.

You can take a look at [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/276151/33075) how you can apply a search criteria.
Basically, if you inject `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` in the contructor, you can then try:

```php
$trackNo = 'TEST_TRACK_NO';
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('track_number', $trackNo);
```

And then get the data with:

```php
$tracks = $this->shipmentTrackRepository->getList($searchCriteria->create())
```

Where `shipmentTrackRepository` is the injected `ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface` interface in the constructor.

It returns the data from that table which has the order id as well.

> @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterface Shipment track interface.

You can then get the order_id using

```php
$orderId = $tracks->getData()[0]['order_id']
```

which you can then supply as an argument in
`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::cancel` to cancel the order.

Comment: See also if `\Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface::getList` helps. I think track id refers to entity_id on that table rather than tracking number, and maybe its a good idea to get the entire list and try to filter it. I'll take a look later and see if I can provide an example.

Comment: Ok..Thank You..I will try

Comment: But Actually I have to call third party API to cancel the order..I have created the order using the third party API..Now to cancel the order I need tracking number..I want to know where to call API to cancel the order from backend in magento 2?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... You want to call the Magento API to cancel the order externally? Or are you trying to cancel the order on the 3rd party and want to send the tracking number to the 3rd party API? Or are you just trying to cancel an order in Magento using a tracking number stored in Magento?

Comment: I am just trying to cancel an order in Magento using a tracking number stored in Magento using CURL for API

Comment: Let me update the answer with possible options.

Comment: Can I modified \app\code\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\order\Cancel.php file directly?

Comment: If you want to modify the logic of the Cancel button in the admin, I would suggest you create a preference or plugin to modify the logic. Never do the changes in the core files directly, or you will lose your changes when an update happens. Also I suggest you install Magento using composer (I see you have everything in app/code)

Comment: Ok.I will try to do